# bash script to verify the ssh public key isn't requested

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I want to ssh to an ip from my bash script and if it asks me to add the public key to the known_hosts file, I want to print a message and exit the script. Also, I don't want to check my known_hosts file because I'm using IDM so the key won't be in known_hosts.  I tried this as a quick test but it seems ssh takes over because it's excepting input:

```
    #!/bin/bash

if ssh localhost | grep -q 'authenticity'; then
   echo "matched"
fi
```

This is the output I currently get:

```
[root@host ~]# sh test.sh
The authenticity of host 'localhost (::1)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:Nw91ZidjeQLA2/pEGoLpk1lRxk22arS9/xQNTU6gck8.
ECDSA key fingerprint is MD5:d7:f0:66:9c:93:2b:2d:64:34:06:ad:c4:1d:8c:c2:a2.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

What I want is if that happen is answer "no" to the above, print "ssh key problem" and exit the script. If that isn't possible, maybe I can answer yes to the above then have the script check known_hosts and error if it's in there?

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid `ssh` asking for these things with `ssh -o BatchMode=yes yourhost`

You'll then find -- and you can already see from your output -- that `grep` doesn't apply for error messages (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12055674/piping-error-messages-with-grep) about that).

If you want to check for a successful login, you can consider doing:

```
if ssh -o BatchMode=yes your.host.name true
then
  echo "Successful login"
fi
```

If you specifically want to check for host key verification:

```
if LC_ALL=C ssh -o BatchMode=yes your.host.name true 2>&1 | grep -q "Host key verification failed"
then
  echo "Invalid host key"
fi
```

The `2>&1` makes sure you grep error messages, and `LC_ALL=C` ensures you get the default English error messages regardless of the user's current language setting.